# Проблемы с CORS . Golang/ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, golang, axios, golang-gin

Пытаюсь со стороны ReactJS(который запускается nodejs сервером) отправить GET запрос на свой api сервер, написанный на golang.

Но вместо удачного запроса возникает ошибка:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5500/authors' from
> origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Как я понял, поскольку это кросс-запросы, то нужно прописать настройки CORS на api сервере, к которому и идут запросы. Но ошибка всё равно не пропадает.

Я использую фрэймворк Gin. Примерно так я указываю конфигурацию CORS.

```
r := gin.New()

r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"PUT", "PATCH", "GET", "POST"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Content-Type"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
        return origin == "*"
    },
    MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
}))

r.GET("/authors", getAuthors)

//Server run
r.Run("localhost:5500") // listen and serve
```

На стороне ReactJS я отправляю запрос на api сервер используя axios. Вот код отправки.

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT",
    },
    mode: 'cors'
};
    
axios
    .get('http://localhost:5500/authors', config)
    .then(response => {
        debugger
        console.log(response)
    })
```

Что я не так делаю?  И как исправить данную ошибку с CORS?

Answer (score 0):

В общем мне нужно лишь было немного отредактировать конфигурацию CORS на сервере.

Вот так я его перенастроил.

```
r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"*"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    AllowOriginFunc: func(origin string) bool {
        return origin == "*"
    },
    MaxAge: 12 * time.Hour,
}))
```